# The left side navigation is missing or incorrectly positioned in Microsoft Edge

Tags: bug, design, sidebar, microsoft-edge

I noticed that the menu to the left sometimes disappear or goes to the bottom of the page.

I only manage to get this result on Microsoft Edge when I scroll down while the page is loading.

Examples of what it can look like:
Here it's completely gone:
[image]

and here it's at the bottom:
[image]

Comment: I can't seem to be able to reproduce this. Is it still happening? If so, what version of Edge are you on?

Comment: I can give it a try on Monday again, it's on my work computer I managed.